# Hazelcast configure file storage

Tags: caching, ehcache, hazelcast

I have a need for a java-cache with file storage, that survives JVM crashes.

Previously I used ehcache, configured with `.heap().disk()`.
However, it has a problem with unclear JVM shutdowns - next startup clears the store.

My only requirement is that at least parts of the data survive a restart.

I tried to use hazelcast, however with following code snippet, even subsequent run of the program returns prints "null".

Please suggest how to configure hazelcast, so that cache.put is written to a disk and loaded on startup.

```
public class HazelcastTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("hazelcast.jcache.provider.type", "server");

    Config config = new Config();
    HotRestartPersistenceConfig hotRestartPersistenceConfig = new HotRestartPersistenceConfig()
        .setEnabled(true)
        .setBaseDir(new File("cache"))
        .setBackupDir(new File("cache/backup"))
        .setParallelism(1)
        .setClusterDataRecoveryPolicy(HotRestartClusterDataRecoveryPolicy.FULL_RECOVERY_ONLY);
    config.setHotRestartPersistenceConfig(hotRestartPersistenceConfig);

    HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);

    CacheConfig<String, String> cacheConfig = new CacheConfig<>();
    cacheConfig.getHotRestartConfig().setEnabled(true);
    cacheConfig.getHotRestartConfig().setFsync(true);

    CachingProvider cachingProvider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
    Cache<String, String> data = cachingProvider.getCacheManager().createCache("data", cacheConfig);

    System.out.println(data.get("test"));
    data.put("test", "value");

    data.close();
    instance.shutdown();
}
```

}

Suggestions for other frameworks that could complete the task are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Igor, Hot Restart is an Enterprise Feature of Hazelcast. You need to use Hazelcast Enterprise edition with a valid License Key.

Do you really need to store in a file, or just persist cache data somewhere else? If you can use a database, you can use `MapStore` which is available in Open Source version & write data to a persistent data store. You can even use `write-behind` mode to speed up writes.

See these sample project: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-map/mapstore